# ECS Execution Role causes log driver failure during container startup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

When using a custom IAM Role as an ECS Task Definition'scustom execution role, our resulting Service wil fail to startup on our ECS instance due to an inability to initialize the CloudWatch logging driver.  Specifically, we see the following errors from ECS agent in CloudWatch:

```
2019-10-24T21:43:10Z [INFO] TaskHandler: Adding event: TaskChange: [arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:REDACTED -> STOPPED, Known Sent: NONE, PullStartedAt: 2019-10-24 21:43:08.499577397 +0000 UTC m=+187.475751716, PullStoppedAt: 2019-10-24 21:43:09.69279918 +0000 UTC m=+188.668973506, ExecutionStoppedAt: 2019-10-24 21:43:10.153954812 +0000 UTC m=+189.130129126, arn:aws:ecs:us-west-1:REDACTED wordpress -> STOPPED, Reason CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: CredentialsEndpointError: failed to load credentials

caused by: Get http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/REDACTED: dial tcp 169.254.170.2:80: connect: connection refused, Known Sent: NONE] sent: false
```

This "connection refused error" used to be a timeout error, but I attempted to debug this issue after reading similar problems by adding iptables entries from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html even though this is a Amazon ECS provisioned CoreOS EC2 instance (not a custom one).

Essentially that link and [other issues similar to mine](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/752#issuecomment-479136951) recommended the following, which change the error to a timeout error at least:

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 169.254.170.2 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:51679
ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.170.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 51679
```

Note that this container definition runs and works completely fine under normal conditions when we don't use a custom IAM execution role in the container definition; but since I am attempting to add an AWS SecretsManager secret in the Task Definition; this requires us to define a custom role that has access to the secret.

EDIT: Here is both the role policy JSON and the cloud-config.yml for the ECS instance:

JSON Policy Role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
        "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
        "ssm:GetParameters",
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "kms:Decrypt"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "${var.aws_mysql_secret_arn}"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

cloud-config.yml

```
coreos:
  units:
   - name: update-engine.service
     command: stop
   - name: amazon-ecs-agent.service
     command: start
     runtime: true
     content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=AWS ECS Agent
       Documentation=https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/
       Requires=docker.socket
       After=docker.socket

       [Service]
       Environment=ECS_CLUSTER=${ecs_cluster_name}
       Environment=ECS_LOGLEVEL=${ecs_log_level}
       Environment=ECS_VERSION=${ecs_agent_version}
       Restart=on-failure
       RestartSec=30
       RestartPreventExitStatus=5
       SyslogIdentifier=ecs-agent
       ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/ecs /var/ecs-data /etc/ecs
       ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill ecs-agent
       ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm ecs-agent
       ExecStartPre=iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 169.254.170.2 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:51679
       ExecStartPre=iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.170.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 51679
       ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:$${ECS_VERSION}
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name ecs-agent \
                                     --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
                                     --volume=/var/log/ecs:/log \
                                     --volume=/var/ecs-data:/data \
                                     --volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
                                     --volume=/run/docker/execdriver/native:/var/lib/docker/execdriver/native:ro \
                                     --publish=127.0.0.1:51678:51678 \
                                     --env=ECS_LOGFILE=/log/ecs-agent.log \
                                     --env=ECS_LOGLEVEL=$${ECS_LOGLEVEL} \
                                     --env=ECS_DATADIR=/data \
                                     --env=ECS_CLUSTER=$${ECS_CLUSTER} \
                                     --env=ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS='["awslogs"]' \
                                     --env=ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE=true \
                                     --log-driver=awslogs \
                                     --log-opt awslogs-region=${aws_region} \
                                     --log-opt awslogs-group=${ecs_log_group_name} \
                                     amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:$${ECS_VERSION}
```

Comment: is your role extends the default or not?

Comment: @Lamanus I'm not sure how to extend the default role, as I don't see it's name when I run the task definition or ECS service without the execution role specified.  Seems to be hidden when by AWS when not explicitly specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for our case was to switch the host of the ECS agent's network mode to "host" mode, rather than bridged mode (--net=host).  This was because ECS agent no longer supports bridged mode.  In addition to this, we added the IP tables rules and localnet.conf to ensure routing was setup correctly.

Here is the resulting template that wound up working for us:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
   - name: iptables-restore.service
     command: start
     runtime: true
   - name: systemd-sysctl.service
     command: start
     runtime: true
   - name: update-engine.service
     command: stop
   - name: amazon-ecs-agent.service
     command: start
     runtime: true
     content: |
       [Unit]
       Description=AWS ECS Agent
       Documentation=https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/
       Requires=docker.socket
       After=docker.socket

       [Service]
       Environment=ECS_CLUSTER=${ecs_cluster_name}
       Environment=ECS_LOGLEVEL=${ecs_log_level}
       Environment=ECS_VERSION=latest
       Restart=on-failure
       RestartSec=30
       RestartPreventExitStatus=5
       SyslogIdentifier=ecs-agent
       ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/ecs /var/ecs-data /etc/ecs
       ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/touch /etc/ecs/ecs.config
       ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill ecs-agent
       ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm ecs-agent
       ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:${ECS_VERSION}
       ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name ecs-agent \
                                     --env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config \
                                     --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
                                     --volume=/var/log/ecs:/log \
                                     --volume=/var/ecs-data:/data \
                                     --volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
                                     --volume=/run/docker/execdriver/native:/var/lib/docker/execdriver/native:ro \
                                     --net=host \
                                     --env=ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true \
                                     --env=ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE_NETWORK_HOST=true \
                                     --env=ECS_LOGFILE=/log/ecs-agent.log \
                                     --env=ECS_LOGLEVEL=${ECS_LOGLEVEL} \
                                     --env=ECS_DATADIR=/data \
                                     --env=ECS_CLUSTER=${ECS_CLUSTER} \
                                     --env=ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS='["awslogs","json-file"]' \
                                     --env=ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE=true \
                                     --log-driver=awslogs \
                                     --log-opt awslogs-region=${aws_region} \
                                     --log-opt awslogs-group=${ecs_log_group_name} \
                                     amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:${ECS_VERSION}
write_files:
  - path: /var/lib/iptables/rules-save
    permissions: 0644
    owner: 'root:root'
    content: |
      *nat
      -A PREROUTING -d 169.254.170.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:51679
      -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.170.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 51679
      COMMIT
  - path: /etc/sysctl.d/localnet.conf
    permissions: 0644
    owner: 'root:root'
    content: |
      net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

Comment: In case someone wonders where all these magics are coming from, it's in the official `ecs-agent` doc: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent#on-other-linux-amis

Answer (score 1):

if you have failure in this case, check 2 options.

1. `ECS execution role policy`'s permission. it should contains `logs:CreateLogStream` and `logs:PutLogEvents`. like :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. you should configure `ecs_agent`'s config for `awslogs` driver.

this config file path is `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` in host. this file should be like :

add `awslogs` driver into `ecs.config`

```
ECS_CLUSTER=test_ecs_cluster
ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS=["awslogs","json-file"]
```

> See :
>
> Here's [a document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Comment: These 2 conditions are unfortunately already in place, there seems to be something else that's required.  Specifically:

1.  My execution role policy already include those permissions as well as a couple other ones I added just in case.  I've updated my question to include the role policy JSON I'm utilizing.

2.  I do ecs_agent in a service level configuration via the cloud-config.ymlto include ECS_CLUSTER and ECS_AVAILABLE_LOGGING_DRIVERS as well as some other parameters, I'll update my question to include these settings.

Comment: @depthfirstdesigner Did you find any way to fix the above issue?

Comment: @Niranjan indeed we did, we had to utilize ECS agent in "host" mode rather than "bridged" network mode as ECS stopped supporting bridged mode.  We also added the routing rules directly in the cloud config template which made things easier.  See the self-answer I just added above for more detail.

Comment: @depthfirstdesigner this dint solve my issue. In cdk taskexecutionrole is automatically getting created and taached to task definition. If i remove this everything work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Although I've checked this only for an ECS task using the Fargate launch type, this could still be relevant for tasks using the EC2 launch type.
This is what has worked for me:

1. Define an IAM policy (let's call it `ECSCloudWatchLogs`) like the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create an IAM Role (let's call it `TaskExecutionRole`) for ECS tasks (trusted relationship `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`) and attach the following policies:

   - `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` (AWS managed policy)
   - `ECSCloudWatchLogs` (created at step 1)
3. Assign the role created in step 2 to your Task execution role (task definition):

[image]

After that I didn't get any more the `failed to initialize logging driver` issue.

Comment: A big thank you! With these steps I was able to create role which has access to create log groups and execute tasks with that. Small note to add, if you are using aws CLI then you'll need to specify that newly created role's ARN in `executionRoleArn` key in your task definition